# Forcing flink to use different kafka-clients jar

Tags: gradle, apache-flink

i am using Flink Connector Kafka 1.8.0. (depends on kafka-clients 2.0.1)

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka_2.12/1.8.0

using gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-connector-kafka
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka_2.12', version: '1.8.0'
```

i wonder if i can force it to use kafka-clients 2.4.0

i wodering if flink supports it, and even so, how it can be configured through 
gradle?

can you assist?

Comment: What have you tried that did not work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can configure that by simply explicitly including the dependency with the version that you want

```
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-connector-kafka_2.12', version: '1.8.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.13', version: '2.4.0'
```

You can test which version has been chosen with

```
gradle dependencies
```